# Publish Synapse Artifacts to Workspace - Status

Tags: azure-synapse

In Synapse Studio, After a click on "Publish" button

[image]

we see in the notification the status of the Action. The process takes currently 45 minutes.
[image]

While it is publishing if we close the page or the browser, and reopen the workspace there is no indicator that it is still publishing or not....

I have looked in Azure portal - Activity log and there is nothing. Even if I wait the process to  complete I don't see any log activity.

Is there another way to know the status of the "publish" action ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to set this up directly. Perhaps you could trigger a pipeline to send a notification in source control when the publish branch updates?

Comment: Also, 45 minutes is a crazy long time for Publish. In my experience, the Publish time correlates to the number of assets being published. A very large update may take up to 10 minutes, but that is rare. Small updates can complete in as little as 30 seconds.

Comment: @JoelCochran I'm using Synapse workspace deployment Extension and I'm not sure if it updates or recreates the artefacts. I don't know what would be a big deployment but my TemplateForWorkspace.json file has 166600 lines

Comment: I'm not familiar with that Extension, but my file is over 200K lines long.

Comment: @JoelCochran Sorry I was out of my mind, Synapse workspace deployment Extension has nothing to do with clicking the Publish button! Actually this extension is used in our deployment pipeline to other environment, after the Publish.
Though it is out of scope of this thread, but how do you migrate your artefacts if your not using this extension ? [CI-CD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery#set-up-a-stage-task-for-azure-synapse-artifacts-deployment)
I understand that 45 minutes to publish is way too long. We'll look at that

Comment: At this point, I'm not sure what we're discussing :-) Migrate artifacts to where?

Comment: Continuous Deployment, after the publish in dev, I guess you're migrating artefacts to Production ? Or maybe you are using git mode also in production

Comment: Yes, Git mode in Production. We use branches for development.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no way to get the publish status after closing the Portal.

You should either keep the Azure Portal open or manually check the components in Azure Synapse which you have published.